# Summarize rows in df

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have following example df:

```
housing = {'year': [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005],
        'moved in': [10, 26, 15, 11, 12],
        'moved out': [4, 15, 23, 1, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(housing, columns = ['year', 'moved in', 'moved out'])
```

Now I want to create a column with calculated values which would show the number of people living in a house in a given year. In the first row there must be calculated the number of people who moved in and out giving the result. In the next row this result should be taken adding the number people who moved in and subtracting the number of people who moved out. The result would be the number of people who still live in the house in this year. I would like to iterate it through the whole df.

Is there a solution for it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a rolling sum over each year's net change.

```
df['current'] = (df['moved in'] - df['moved out']).rolling(window=len(df), min_periods=1).sum()
print(df)
   year  moved in  moved out  current
0  2001        10          4      6.0
1  2002        26         15     17.0
2  2003        15         23      9.0
3  2004        11          1     19.0
4  2005        12          3     28.0
```

With the `net change` column:

```
df['net change'] = df['moved in'] - df['moved out']
df['current'] = df['net change'].rolling(window=len(df), min_periods=1).sum()
print(df)
   year  moved in  moved out  net change  current
0  2001        10          4           6      6.0
1  2002        26         15          11     17.0
2  2003        15         23          -8      9.0
3  2004        11          1          10     19.0
4  2005        12          3           9     28.0
```